# C# CsQuery as Html Documents Builder

Tags: c#, csquery

So far I used **HtmlAgilityPack** for building Html documents.

The problem is that it is not stable, I get Stackoverflow Exceptions and it doesn't support jQuery syntax.

What I am trying to use to build Html documents is **CsQuery**.

My question is:
Is it designated for building Html documents?

I like the functions it offers, but I cannot render the modified html document.

For example:

```
  CQ fragment= CQ.CreateFragment("<p>some text</p>");
  CQ html = CQ.CreateFromFile(@"index.html");
  CQ modified_html= html.Select("#test").Append(fragment);
```

Which means, I want to append **fragment** variable to element with id "test".

the problem is that I expect modified_html.Render() to return the modified version (including **< p> sometext < /p>** added to #test element), but it actually doesn't!!!

is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it does. I also checked with your code, it do append `<p>some text</p>` to the `modified_html`. The only possible issue I can think: there is no element with id = "test" in index.html. You may also want to save modified html to file so it will be easier for you to examine the output :

```
modified_html.Save(@"index_modified.html");
```